# jQuery AJAX Post using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I am getting an error back on a jQuery ajax post.

The error I receive in IE is SyntaxError: Invalid character.

The entire project can be found at: http://dragsort.codeplex.com/

When you move one of the boxes to another location (click and drag) the ajax post occurs.

In order to display the error I had to add the error ajax property to the jQuery ajax call.

```
function saveOrder() {
var data = $("#gallery li").map(function() { return $(this).attr("itemID"); }).get();
$.ajax({ 
    url: "example.aspx/SaveListOrder", 
    data: '{ids:["' + data.join('","') + '"]}', 
    dataType: "json", 
    type: "POST", 
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    error: function(data, status, jqXHR) { alert(jqXHR); }
});
};
```

Code behind Method

```
[WebMethod]
public static void SaveListOrder(int[] ids)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ids.Length; i++)
    {
        int id = ids[i];
        int ordinal = i;
        //...
    }
}
```

Any ideas on what the issue is?  Thanks in advance.

**EDIT/ANSWER:**

The problem is in the web.config. I added the following httpModule in the web.config

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>    
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

If anyone would like to elaborate on why this is needed that would be great.  I'll create a post as the answer once i'm allowed to do so.

Thanks!

Comment: Try setting `data` to an actual javascript object instead of a json formatted string.

Comment: Seems like a json error. Can you show the resulting json data?

Comment: I am unsure what you mean 'Can you show the resulting json data' and unsure on how to pass a JavaScript object and interpret it in the WebMethod.

Comment: The data you're sending with the ajax request. Use `alert('{ids:["' + data.join('","') + '"]}')` or something.

Comment: When I display the data using an alert, I get the data expected:

{ids:["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"]}

Comment: I notice you're using IE, but you can view the resulting json data by using Firebug in Firefox.  If you open the Firebug 'script' tab, you should be able to put a breakpoint on your saveOrder() function, and when the breakpoint is hit, you can step through the function & hover over the data object and see what it contains.

Comment: Stepping through FireBug, the data object contains values 0 through 10.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in SaveListOrder does the ids property have the correct value?

Comment: I edited my post to include my solution.  I'll create the answer once I'm allowed to do so.  Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the web.config. I added the following httpModule in the web.config

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>    
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

If anyone would like to elaborate on why this is needed that would be great.  I'll create a post as the answer once i'm allowed to do so.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Object keys must be double-quoted strings. In fact, all strings in JSON must be envlosed in double quotes. In your code, the `ids` isn't double-quoted. You should surround it with double-quotes like this.

```
data: '{"ids":["' + data.join('","') + '"]}',
```

You can use [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to easily validate JSON.

Comment: I understand what you are getting at, but I tried your modification with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `traditional: true` to your AJAX call. I believe you have to set that to get an array to pass correctly. Like this

```
    $.ajax({ 
       url: "example.aspx/SaveListOrder", 
       traditional: true,
       data: '{ids:["' + data.join('","') + '"]}', 
       dataType: "json", 
       type: "POST", 
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       error: function(data, status, jqXHR) { alert(jqXHR); }
   });
```

Comment: I added traditional: true with no luck.  I'm still investigating.  I posted the project link in my post.  Can anyone download it and give it a try?

Answer (score 0):

It may have to do with the response you are returning. I think IE requires that the application also respond with a json content type.